# Error programming progressDialog

Tags: android, syntax-error, progressdialog

i'm trying do a progressDialog into an asynctask, but when i call the context "mainactivity.this" java show this message "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"

look the code

```
static class Tarea1 extends AsyncTask<ListView, String, CityAdapter>{

    Context contexto;
    ListView list;
    InputStream is;
    ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();

    public void cargarContenido(Context contexto){
        this.contexto = contexto;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){
          super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);//here is the error
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Since you are providing a context to your asynctask, why not doing `ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(contexto);`?

Comment: Ok, usa this.getAppContext(); ///new ProgressDialog(this.getAppContext());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `Tarea1` class is defined as static.  You can't reference objects from the outer class when the inner class is static.

ZouZou is correct in his comment, since you are passing the context into the constructor, you should just use `this.context` instead.  Just make sure the context you are passing is an Activity context.

Otherwise, you could just remove the `static` qualifier.  It's a matter of taste but I prefer to use static inner classes like you have to keep them more decoupled from the outer class.  That way, if/when you move it to it's own file, you don't have to pry them apart.